Finding the discontinuities of $\text{inf}_i (|x - q_i| 2^i)$

Let $q_i$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers, and let
$f(x) = \text{infimum}_i (|x - q_i| 2^i)$
obviously f(x) is 0 and continuous at every rational number.
Additionally, f is discontinuous at every x where f(x) is nonzero, since there are rational numbers arbitrarily close by.
The measure of the points for which $f(x) < 1/2$ is less than $\sum_i 1/2^i$, so f is greater than 1/2 (and so discontinuous) on a set of infinite measure.
But it can't be nonzero exactly on all the irrationals, because it is discontinuous where it is nonzero, and discontinuities form an $F\sigma$ set.
My question is, what is the set on which f is discontinuous? It has to be a countable union of closed sets, have nonzero measure, and contain no rational numbers- aren't those requirements contradictory? Alternatively, what is the common name of this function (as I doubt that I invented it, and with the name I can google my way to answers)

Given any sequnce $(\epsilon_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\epsilon_n>0$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0}\epsilon_n<\infty$ one can look at the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{n\geq 0}(q_n-\epsilon_n, q_n+\epsilon_n)$. This set is closed, has infinite measure and is disjoint from $\mathbb{Q}$. So these requirements are not contradictory. I see that it looks contradictory though, the notions of measure and category are somehow orthogonal, in the sense that there are meager sets with full measure. In your case, the set of discontinuity points is meager. As $f(x)<\epsilon$ implies that $x\in \bigcup_{n\geq 0}(q_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}, q_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n})$ and this set has measure $\leq \epsilon$, the set of continuity points is a null-set.
Interestingly, a Borel measurable function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is always continuous on a comeager set and on a set with complement of measure less than any given $\epsilon>0$ - of course with the restricted topology (see for example in Classical Descriptive Set Theory by A. Kechris). I don't know if the functions you consider have a name assigned to them.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
